# Android ssl: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate (yet again)

Tags: android, ssl, https, openssl

I've got a web site that I'm enabling ssl on for a RESTful service. We have registered with RapidSSL, installed the certs, and it passes the [RapidSSL checker](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO9556&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US). I'm able to access the site with various browsers, including the android browsers (built in, firefox and opera) with no problems, no warnings.

However, when I try to access it with my android app, I get the following exception:

```
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider: Error executing request: No peer certificate
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:259)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-11 20:04:05.586   363   381 E HttpProvider:  at com.xxxxx.netlib.http.HttpProvider.executeRequest(HttpProvider.java:75)
```

This occurs on android 2.3.3 on the emulator and on a 3.2 tablet. I've seen lots of hits on this, but nothing I've found helps me to fix the issue.

More data:

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile www.xxxxx.com.pem -connect www.xxxxx.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = "GeoTrust, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL CA
verify return:1
depth=0 serialNumber = 1-7wArtEjdTwJ94d5iVDooDmmC4mXyVj, OU = GT82425783, OU = See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12, OU = Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R), CN = www.xxxxx.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/serialNumber=1-7wArtEjdTwJ94d5iVDooDmmC4mXyVj/OU=GT82425783/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=www.xxxxx.com
  i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
  i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
  i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
[snip]
```

The code I'm running to set up the client:

```
public class HttpProvider implements INetworkProvider {
  private static final String LOG = "HttpProvider";
  protected DefaultHttpClient client;

  public HttpProvider() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));

    client = new DefaultHttpClient(
      new ThreadSafeClientConnManager((new BasicHttpParams()), registry), new BasicHttpParams()
    );
  }
[snip]
```

I've also tried with STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER and still no joy.

From what I understand I shouldn't need to set up any custom truststores or keystores since I'm registered with a recognized cert provider.

I'm very new with ssl and find I'm swimming in a sea of Three Letter Acronyms, and I was hoping someone here may be able to give me a shove in the right direction.

Comment: I've figured out how to dump out the system trust store, and I don't see RapidSSL in there, despite posts saying it was in honeycomb. I will try to create my own truststore and see what happens.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38598593/2301721 (using HttpsURLConnection)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After piles of digging and experimentation, I finally realized that the url I was using had hard coded port 80 instead of defaulting to 443. Dumb dumb dumb.

The answer to this question [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) helped tremendously for my understanding of SSL.