# Android JSON Parser with DefaultHttpClient and POST over SSL

Tags: java, android, json, ssl, https

First, sorry for my bad english! My Problem: With this JSONParser.java I want to connect to a SSL-secured server. How to change my code to make it work?

**ADDITION: The SSL Certificate is a self-signed certificate!**

```java
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    public JSONParser() {}
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List params) {
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {sb.append(line).append("n");}
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Logcat output (i had to censor the packagename):

```
09-01 11:26:14.759    1462-1462/ *package_name* W/ActivityThread: Application *package_name* is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-01 11:26:14.806    1462-1462/ *package_name* I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
09-01 11:26:14.887    1462-1467/ *package_name* I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
09-01 11:26:15.031    1462-1462/ *package_name* I/System.out: Debugger has connected
09-01 11:26:15.031    1462-1462/ *package_name* I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-01 11:26:17.673    1462-1462/ *package_name* I/System.out: debugger has settled (1391)
09-01 11:26:21.538    1462-1462/ *package_name* W/ResourceType: Entry identifier 0x119 is larger than entry count 0xab
09-01 11:26:28.164    1462-1462/ *package_name* W/KeyCharacterMap: No keyboard for id 0
09-01 11:26:28.164    1462-1462/ *package_name* W/KeyCharacterMap: Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
09-01 11:26:44.737    1462-1462/ *package_name* D/dalvikvm: GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 164K, 50% free 2797K/5575K, external 3181K/3266K, paused 74ms
09-01 11:26:57.325    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
09-01 11:26:57.349    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:258)
09-01 11:26:57.349    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
09-01 11:26:57.423    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
09-01 11:26:57.447    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
09-01 11:26:57.473    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-01 11:26:57.473    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-01 11:26:57.533    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
09-01 11:26:57.556    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-01 11:26:57.556    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-01 11:26:57.608    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-01 11:26:57.608    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at *package_name*.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:36)
09-01 11:26:57.608    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at *package_name*.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:38)
09-01 11:26:57.656    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at *package_name*.Login$ProcessLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:214)
09-01 11:26:57.682    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at *package_name*.Login$ProcessLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:194)
09-01 11:26:57.682    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-01 11:26:57.706    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-01 11:26:57.706    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-01 11:26:57.706    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-01 11:26:57.741    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-01 11:26:57.741    1462-1475/ *package_name* W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-01 11:26:57.741    1462-1475/ *package_name* E/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 11:26:57.869    1462-1475/ *package_name* E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
09-01 11:26:57.892    1462-1462/ *package_name* D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-01 11:26:57.892    1462-1462/ *package_name* W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-01 11:26:58.016    1462-1462/ *package_name* E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at *package_name*.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:219)
            at *package_name*.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:194)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what problem are u facing ? error ? exception ?

Comment: The app crashes and Logcat says:
`W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate`
`E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException`
`E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of`

Comment: @atom_dad add your logcat in question itself please.

Answer (score 0):

SSLPeerUnverifiedExcption is not thrown because of your android code.The exception that is thrown when the identity of a peer has not been verified.There might be some server side issue or you are using a bad url. Hence, you are not able to connect with the server.

Check these

[Android ssl: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate (yet again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923380/android-ssl-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate-yet)

[Safely fixing: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126372/safely-fixing-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate)

[javax.net.ssl.sslpeerunverifiedexception no peer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159657/javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate)

Comment: I edited my code, but the errors still are there.. I think it is because it is a self-signed certificate

Comment: After some changes, Logcat says 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer'