# What can cause javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl

I'm getting javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate on Android device when trying connect to server.

I've tried different solutions like disabling certificate check (just for debug purpose) or to enable old cipher algorithms and nothing worked.

When I'm opening this url in browser everything seems fine however I see message "This site uses a weak security configuration(SHA-1 signatures)". 
Could it be the reason of this exception?

Comment: Are you using the right port? 443 instead of 80? As per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923380/android-ssl-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate-yet

Comment: @ReinerDG Yes port 443